# Run time error '1004' when importing xls file from url

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a macro which import data from the following url:
www.gfigroup.com/docs/sef/marketdata/2014-04-08_daily_trade_data.xls.
If you copy and paste it in your browser, it'll import an xls file.
The code I use is the following:

```
Dim wbMe As Workbook
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim w As Integer
Dim wbURL As Workbook
Dim url As String

Set wbMe = ThisWorkbook
url = "www.gfigroup.com/docs/sef/marketdata/2014-04-08_daily_trade_data.xls"
Set wbURL = Workbooks.Open(url)

'## Add code to copy this data to your workbook and/or manipulate the data...'
w = wbMe.Sheets.Count

'## Add a new worksheet to the end of ThisWorkbook:'
Set wsNew = wbMe.Sheets.Add(After:=wbMe.Sheets(w))

'## Copy & Paste this data in to our new worksheet:'
wbURL.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=wsNew.Range("A2")

'## Close the downloaded version which we no longer need:'
wbURL.Close
```

Though, when I run it' I have this Run time error '1004' saying that it could not find the ressource, and asking if it has been deleted or renamed.
Has anyone already faced this problem? And eventually found a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `http://` to the beginning of the web address and it should work..

```
url = "http://www.gfigroup.com/docs/sef/marketdata/2014-04-08_daily_trade_data.xls"
```

Comment: Cool. Can't believe it was so simple.